# SupportMapFragment not showing map in android

Tags: android, dictionary, supportmapfragment

I was trying the new MapFragment support for android 2.3

my programe runs fine.. with no errors.

BUT I am not able to see the Map. I can only see the + and - signs but no map tiles.

[here is the snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mVMWV.jpg)

Following is the my code

**main activity**

```
package com.plotter;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.view.Menu;

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

public FragmentManager fManager ;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main_activity_layout);

    fManager = getSupportFragmentManager();

    loadMapFragment();
}

private void loadMapFragment() {
    PlotterFragment plotterFragment = new PlotterFragment();
    FragmentTransaction ft = fManager.beginTransaction();
    ft.replace(R.id.fragmentsFrameLayout, plotterFragment);
    ft.addToBackStack(null);
    ft.commit();
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_activity_layout, menu);
    return true;
}



}
```

**fragment class**

```
package com.plotter;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;

public class PlotterFragment extends SupportMapFragment {

private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
private View view;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle bundle) {
    super.onCreateView(inflater, container, bundle);

    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.plotter_fragment_layout, container,
            false);
    layoutInflater = inflater;
    view = v;

    return v;

}

}
```

**fragment class layout**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:id="@+id/map"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"/>
```

**manifeast file**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.plotter"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="9"
    android:targetSdkVersion="16" />



<permission
      android:name="com.plotter.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
      android:protectionLevel="signature"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.plotter.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>

<uses-permission android:name = "android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name = "android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name = "android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name = "android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>

    <uses-feature
  android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
  android:required="true"/>




<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.plotter.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <meta-data
android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
android:value="AIzaSyDr9JzCACZq0TonQ1ONreDtRwe_5Cu-z6A"/>
</application>

</manifest>
```

**main activity layout**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<FrameLayout android:id = "@+id/fragmentsFrameLayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true">

</FrameLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: How are you able to set a marker from inside the Fragment that extends SupportFrameActivity ?